# (MYSQL) Auto_increment a temporary table based off the max id of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've got mySQL code here for a table with a bunch of columns and a rowID field. The rowID field is a primary key and unique index. Within a stored procedure, im creating a temporary table to do some data manipulation, and i want the temporary table to start with the MAX(rowID)+1 in the first table. I've got this code right now:

```
set @auto_incID = (SELECT (MAX(rowID)+1) from `mytable`); 

set @sql = concat('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `myTempTable` auto_increment = ',@auto_incID, ' SELECT * FROM mytable where items = 20;');
PREPARE st FROM @sql;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

The problem is, this code returns an error code of 1062: duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'. Upon further inspection, it seems that auto_increment isn't actually updating the temporary table, and it's just receiving the entries from the first table as they are (i.e. their rowID stays the same, doesnt start from the MAX(rowID)+1. Am I making a mistake? Or is this not possible?

Comment: SELECT * copies all column values without any change. Your `auto_increment` will be applied only after trable creation.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the info, I figured as much. Is there a feasible way to perform what I'm intending to do then?

Comment: Easily. Simply break the asterisk key on your keyboard, and use it never except `COUNT(*)`. Then list all columns both in INSERT and SELECT parts, and put NULL literal in SELECT for `id` coluimn.

Comment: @Akina Would you be so kind as to provide a small example of what you mean by "put a NULL literal in SELECT for ```id``` column?"

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```sql
-- Create source table
CREATE TABLE old (old_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, old_value INT);
-- Fill it with some data
INSERT INTO old (old_value) VALUES (11), (22);
-- Create new table copying the data and reassigning the primary key values
CREATE TABLE new (new_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, new_value INT) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 
    SELECT null AS new_id, old_value AS new_value FROM old;
```

See the result on the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dec5fd42e3f45b8f27e7be83981a37a3)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now! Thank you, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @PrinceofCats Pay attention that output columns in SELECT part of last query are aliased with the column names of new table. This is COMPULSORY!

Comment: Right, I figured I couldn't use the same names from the old table. Thank you!

Comment: @PrinceofCats No. The column names in CREATE part and column aliases in SELECT part must match strictly - if an alias is absent in columns list then one more column will be added into the structure, and if backward then NULL/DEFAULT will be assigned (or error raised if a column is not nullable and has no default value).

Comment: Right, I figured that. What I'm saying is that I didn't think I could assign column names matching those in the old table to the new table in my CREATE statement, i.e. using your earlier example, i can't do: ```CREATE TABLE new (old_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY...) ``` where the column name in the new table matches that of the old one. Is that right?

Comment: @PrinceofCats *What I'm saying is that I didn't think I could assign column names matching those in the old table to the new table in my CREATE statement, i.e. using your earlier example, i can't do* You can easily. But, remembering the above, you must NOT have a column with the name `old_id` in SELECT's part output - i.e. do not use such alias and assign another alias to the column with this name if exists.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand you now. Thank you!